# Setting a button disabled to false as soon as input is enter?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a little issue with my button not functioning how I would like. So I'm trying to get my button to set disabled to false as soon as text input has been entered in put text field. But currently it only works after the text field focus has changed.

I’ve added my code in as an example, but I’m not really to sure how I can make this instant without the need to click off the text field.

```js
function checkInput() {
  var tbValue = document.getElementById('tb').value;
  if (tbValue != '') {
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputElement" id="tb" autocomplete="off" onchange="checkInput()">

<input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Next" disabled>
```

Comment: Instead of the 'onchange' event you should use the 'oninput' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyup` (triggered after any key is released) event or `oninput` (value has changed) instead of `onchange` (triggered only if input lose focus).

```js
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
const input = document.getElementById('tb');

function checkInput() {
  nextButton.disabled = !input.value;
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputElement" id="tb" autocomplete="off" oninput="checkInput()">
<input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Next" disabled>
```

#### Tips:

Your solution won't active `disabled` again. I've replaced your `if` statement with explicit assignment.

Selecting your element over and over again with every `keyup` is not effective neither. I've selected them once before and assigned them to constant variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
const tb = document.getElementById('tb');

// use JavaScript to bind your event-handling, rather than
// using inline event-handlers in the HTML; this makes
// future maintenance a little easier since you only have
// one file to check.
// Here, we're reacting the 'change' event (which includes
// keypress, keyup, paste and most other events in which
// the value of the element is likely to change):
tb.addEventListener('input', checkInput);

// we've condensed your function a little:
function checkInput() {

  // retrieve the element you want to change and assign
  // it to a named variable:
  const button = document.getElementById('next');

  // here we update the disabled property; if the trimmed
  // length of the input's value (the 'this') is zero,
  // the button is true; otherwise it is false:
  button.disabled = this.value.trim().length === 0;
}
```

```js
const tb = document.getElementById('tb');

tb.addEventListener('input', checkInput);

function checkInput() {
  const button = document.getElementById('next');
  button.disabled = this.value.trim().length === 0;
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputElement" id="tb" autocomplete="off">
<input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Next" disabled>
```

It's also somewhat possible — though likely inadvisable — to emulate the behaviour you desire using CSS:

```
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  /* the usual pointer-event setting for interactivity: */
  pointer-events: normal;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}

/* here we look for an element of class="inputElement"
   that is showing its placeholder (using the CSS pseudo-
   class ':placeholder-shown') and selecting its adjacent
   sibling (with the '+' combinator) matching an <input>
   element of class="btn". If this selecter matches then
   the input.btn element will not receive pointer-events
   (click, mousedown, hover...) and 'look' disabled, though
   the presentation is entirely down to your tastes: */
.inputElement:placeholder-shown+input.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
}
```

Because of this approach, this does require that a `placeholder` attribute be set on the `.inputElement` element.

```css
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  pointer-events: normal;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}

.inputElement:placeholder-shown+input.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputElement" id="tb" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter something. Anything.">
<input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Next">
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`inputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 0):

If you accept jquery then this is your solution

```js
$("#tb").on("input",function() 
{
   let val=$(this).val();
   if(val.length > 0)
   {
      $("#next").attr("disabled","disabled");
   }
   else
   {
      $("#next").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **keyup**

```js
function checkInput() {
  var tbValue = document.getElementById('tb').value;
  if (tbValue) {
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = false;
  } else {
   document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
}
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
}

.inputElement {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputElement" id="tb" autocomplete="off" onkeyup ="checkInput()">

<input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Next" disabled>
```